# Removing Extra Whitespace in C++

Tags: c++, string, c++11, dictionary, whitespace

I'm trying to write code that reads in from a file, or standard input, and causes all whitespace in the file, or standard input, to be "squished", meaning that only the last whitespace character in a sequence of whitespace is printed.  My approach was to create a map with every word as a key and the whitespace after that word as it's value.  This might be problematic as I would need the map's contents to be printed in order of insertion and I would also have duplicate keys.  I found out about    std::unordered_multimap   but I am having trouble figuring out how I would go about implementing it.

Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    string filename;
    char input;
    map<string, string> words;
    ostringstream os;
    string word = "";
    string spaces = "";

    filename = argv[argc-1];
    ifstream infile(filename);

    while ( infile.get(input) ) {
        os << input;
    }

    string filecontents = os.str();

    for (int i = 0; i < filecontents.length(); ++i) {
        if ( !isspace(filecontents[i])) {
            if (spaces.length() >= 1) {
                words[word] = spaces;
                word = "";
                spaces = "";
                word += filecontents[i];
            }

            else {
                word += filecontents[i];
            }
        }

        else {
            spaces += filecontents[i];
        }
    }

    words[word] = "";

    for (const auto& p : words) {
        cout << p.first << p.second.back();
    }
```

File:

```
potato   milk   

sausage
```

Output:

```
milk
potato sausage
```

Maybe theres a better way to go about doing this?  I should add that I am new to C++, well, C in general.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there is no argument specified on the command line -- you're kind of in trouble aren't you?

Comment: Neither `map` nor `unordered_multimap` nor any of the associative containers will preserve the order of insertion.  How about just a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>>`?

Comment: Maybe you just need to store the words by themselves as they all have exactly **one** space separating them? `std::vector<std::string>`

Comment: Being new or knowledgeable about C is only slightly related to C++.  They're different languages, and although they share some syntaxes and features in common, the best way to do some one thing in the two languages is often entirely different.

Comment: _"I am new to C++, well, C in general"_ It sounds like you think C++ is a kind of C. It is not

Comment: @aschepler Going to try this.

Comment: Hey @aschepler, this seemed to work!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You may be overthinking the logic quite a bit. If you want to be able to read from the filename given as the first argument or from `stdin` if no argument is given, you can create a function that reads a `string` from the input stream and simply outputs all words separated by a space (handling the first word specially) by passing an `istream` reference to the function and either passing the open `ifstream` or `std::cin`.

A short example could be something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void squishws (std::istream& in)
{
    bool first = true;
    std::string str;

    while (in >> str)   /* while words read */
        if (first) {    /* no space before 1st word */
            std::cout << str;
            first = false;
        }
        else            /* output remaining words with 1 space */
            std::cout << " " << str;

    std::cout << "\n";  /* tidy up with newline */

}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc > 1) {     /* read from file if given as argument */
        std::ifstream f (argv[1]);
        if (f.is_open()) 
            squishws (f);
        else {
            std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else {  /* read from stdin */
        squishws (std::cin);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can add an output file reference, as required, or simply redirect the output to an output file on the command line.

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/wswords.txt
this       is         a

file    with


multiple

whitespace.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/file_rmwhitespace < dat/wswords.txt
this is a file with multiple whitespace.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the stream extraction operator overload for `std::string` eats whitespaces, you could use that, then add the space to the input:

```
std::string word;
while (data_file >> word)
{
  std::cout << word << " ";
}
```

If you want to input on a line by line basis, you can do similar with `std::istringstream`:

```
std::string text_line;
while (std::getline(data_file, text_line))
{
  std::string word;
  std::istringstream text_stream(text_line);
  while (text_stream >> word)
  {
    std::cout << word << " ";
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

You may want to add some addition logic that removes the extra space at the end of a line.