# C++ Reading a filename from stdin

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to build a version of wc, and one of the key abilities of this program is that you can specify files in two ways:

```
wc file.txt
```

and

```
wc < file.txt
```

I have figured out how to implement the first way, but I am struggling with the second way. How could I approach this?

Comment: That pipe (`<`) opens the file and connects it to the program's standard input. So the program can just read from `std::cin`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Not sure how to do that exactly. I tried this:
`if (argv[argc - 1] == "-w" || argv[argc - 1] == "-l" || argv[argc - 1] == "-c") {
        fileName = cin;
    } else {
        fileName = argv[argc - 1];
    }`
and it threw a bunch of errors

Comment: Pipes are set up by the OS; they're transparent. Just read the incoming data from `std::cin`. Get that working before you try to deal with command-line parameters.

Comment: The basic approach is to either open a `std::istream` for the filename and pass the open stream to a function as reference (e.g. `std::istream&`), or if no filename is provide pass `std::cin` instead. There is an example here [Removing Extra Whitespace in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836880/removing-extra-whitespace-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

The way tools like this work, which includes many others like `grep`, is if there's no arguments on the command-line that specify file-names, input is read from `std::cin`.

In a simple sense, if `argc` is 1 then you have only the executable name as an argument so no files were specified. In a more practical situation you'd use something like [an argument parser](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html) which may interpret various flags, but which will give a count of non-flag arguments.